# Get XML Element With a Prefix in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I am trying to get an element with prefix "media:group" to get the number of views from the element media:statistics:

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  var videos=root.getChildren("entry",atom);
  for (var  i=0;i<videos.length;i++){ 
    var video=videos[i];
    //how do I get the element media:group
  }
```

XML (https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q):

```
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q"/>
<id>yt:channel:UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q</id>
<yt:channelId>UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q</yt:channelId>
<title>Hyram</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q"/>
<author>
<name>Hyram</name>
<uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q</uri>
</author>
<published>2015-11-17T07:07:31+00:00</published>
<entry>
<id>yt:video:bXeVI2246Eg</id>
<yt:videoId>bXeVI2246Eg</yt:videoId>
<yt:channelId>UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q</yt:channelId>
<title>What to Use Instead of Makeup Wipes</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXeVI2246Eg"/>
<author>
<name>Hyram</name>
<uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q</uri>
</author>
<published>2020-11-26T21:32:50+00:00</published>
<updated>2020-11-27T02:32:18+00:00</updated>
<media:group>
<media:title>What to Use Instead of Makeup Wipes</media:title>
<media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/bXeVI2246Eg?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
<media:thumbnail url="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bXeVI2246Eg/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
<media:description>Subscribe to learn how to perfect YOUR skin care routine! ✨ ✨ PRODUCTS MENTIONED ✨ CLEANSING BALM Neutrogena Cleansing Balm*: https://shop-links.co/1724544741800114240 Burts Bees Cleansing Balm*: https://shop-links.co/1724544760705329807 Then I Met You Cleansing Balm*: https://shop-links.co/1724544779685642335 CLEANSING OIL iUnik Calendula Cleansing Oil*: https://shop-links.co/1724544801584644839 Purito From Green Cleansing Oil*: https://shop-links.co/1724544824269308137 Caudalie Makeup Removing Cleansing Oil*: https://shop-links.co/1724544839933711688 CLEANSING WATER BioDerma Sensibio Water*: https://shop-links.co/1724544860227221644 Garnier Skin Cleansing Water*: https://shop-links.co/1724544878277387668 Simple Kind To Skin Water*: https://shop-links.co/1724544898130706627 ✨ VIDEOS MENTIONED ✨ Skin Care 101 Series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_J2v0yTbjr4TBCIvVHfeoDRWIPfSz5QP How to Oil Cleanse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWyDSxvpfQs Be sure to SUBSCRIBE to my channel to learn how to perfect your skin care routine every week! :) _______________________________________________________________  Each purchase supports me to keep working as hard as I can to make videos for you guys! Thank you for the support :)</media:description>
<media:community>
<media:starRating count="7240" average="4.98" min="1" max="5"/>
<media:statistics views="101781"/>
</media:community>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `media:group` from `xml` using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- From your sample XML data, it is found that the name space of "media" is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/`. This is used for retrieving the values of `media:group` and `media:statistics`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q";
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  var media = XmlService.getNamespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
  var yt = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015");
  var videos = root.getChildren("entry", atom);
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var videoId = videos[i].getChild("videoId", yt).getValue();
    var group = videos[i].getChild("group", media).getChildren();
    var temp1 = {videoId: videoId};
    for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
      var g = group[j];
      var v = g.getValue();
      if (v) {
        var ch = g.getChildren();
        if (ch.length == 0) {
          temp1[g.getName()] = v;
        } else {
          var temp2 = {};
          for (var k = 0; k < ch.length; k++) {
            var att = ch[k].getAttributes();
            var temp3 = {};
            for (var l = 0; l < att.length; l++) {
              temp3[att[l].getName()] = att[l].getValue()
            }
            temp2[ch[k].getName()] = temp3;
          }
          temp1[g.getName()] = temp2;
        }
      } else {
        temp1[g.getName()] = g.getAttribute("url").getValue();
      }
    }
    result.push(temp1);
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following value is returned.

```
[
  {
    "videoId": "###",
    "title": "###",
    "content": "###",
    "thumbnail": "###",
    "description": "###",
    "community": {
      "starRating": {
        "count": "#",
        "average": "#",
        "min": "#",
        "max": "#"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "views": "#"
      }
    }
  },
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve only the value of `views` of `statistics`, you can also use the following script. In this script, the result values are returned as the key of `videoId`.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC2sYit3cZ2CuD_8FHYH7O_Q";
      var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
      var root = document.getRootElement();
      var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
      var media = XmlService.getNamespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
      var yt = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015");
      var videos = root.getChildren("entry", atom);
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var videoId = videos[i].getChild("videoId", yt).getValue();
        var views = videos[i].getChild("group", media).getChild("community", media).getChild("statistics", media).getAttribute("views").getValue();
        result.push({[videoId]: views});
      }
      console.log(result)
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)